# store values after groupby and loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pandas-loc

using `df` to select **two columns** `col_1` and `col_2` after `groupby` and `loc` and store at variable `a` in **dataframe** format

**Python Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Gender=['M', 'F', 'M', 'F',
                           'F', 'M', 'M', np.nan],
                   State=['NY','IL', 'NY', 'CA',
                          'IL', 'CA', 'CA', 'IL'],
                   col_1=[10,20,30,np.nan,40,50,60,70],
                   col_2=[1,6,2,4,6,9,np.nan,3]))

d = df.groupby(['Gender','State']).sum()
d.loc['F']
```

**Execution Result**

```
       col_1    col_2
State       
CA     0.0      4.0
IL     60.0     12.0
```

**Expected Result** **(dataframe format)**

```
  a = 
           col_1    col_2
   
           0.0      4.0
           60.0     12.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the index after obtaining grupby data `d`.

```py
print(d.loc['F'].reset_index(drop=True))

   col_1  col_2
0    0.0    4.0
1   60.0   12.0
```